# how to convert Async.js eachSeries example to Bluebird Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async.js

I'm looking into Promises and wondering if anyone familiar with Async.js can demonstrate how to do the following using Bluebird promises. this is the simplest straightforward example I could think of to demonstrate Async.js eachSeries.
For anyone not familiar with Async.js this example runs the same process on each one of the array elements, running in serial (one after the other and not in parallel), then executing code after all async operations completed.

```
var async = require('async');

var items = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; // this is to simulate an array of items to process

async.eachSeries(items,
    function(item, callback){
        console.log('start processing item:',item);
        //simulate some async process like a db CRUD or http call...
        var randomExecutionTime = Math.random() * 2000;
        setTimeout(function(index){
                        //this code runs when the async process is done
                        console.log('async Operation Finished. item:',index);
                      callback(); //call the next item function
                    },randomExecutionTime,item);
    },
    function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('Got an error')
        }else{
            console.log('All tasks are done now...');
        }
    }
);
```

Cheers
Ajar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reformatted and dropped comments, but this has the same behavior as your `async` code.  The key is `Promise.each`, which works serially.  Note that `Promise.each` resolves to the original array.  That is, if you take an argument in the function passed to that final `then`, it will get `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

`Promise.delay` is a simple wrapper around `setTimeout`, essentially.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var items = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

Promise.each(items, function(item) {
  console.log('start processing item:',item);
  var randomExecutionTime = Math.random() * 2000;
  return Promise.delay(randomExecutionTime)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('async Operation Finished. item:', item);
  });
}).then(function() {
  console.log('All tasks are done now...');
}).catch(function() {
  console.log('Got an error')
});
```